# Infinite loop and access error on app startup on model init

Tags: ios

Please help....I'm losing my mind trying to figure out this problem.
I'm fairly new to iOS so don't go too hard on me if it's something obvious! ;)

I'm using xcode 4.6 and targeting iPhone6.1 Simulator.

I get the following error when starting up my app:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2
```

There are hundres of threads appearing in Debug Navigator which leads to to believe there is some sort of infinite loop somewhere (I just cannot see where).

The error occurs beside *(id)init* in *PlayingCardDeck.m* after entering it from *ViewController.m* at line:

```
Card *card = [self.deck drawRandonCard];
```

ViewConrtoller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (nonatomic) int flipCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Deck *deck;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize deck = _deck;

- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
    self.flipCount++;
}

- (void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
{
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", self.flipCount];
}

- (Deck *)deck
{
    if (!_deck) _deck = [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
    return _deck;
}

- (void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons
{
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
    for (UIButton *cardButton in cardButtons)
    {
        Card *card = [self.deck drawRandonCard];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}

@end
```

Deck.m

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface Deck()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cards;

@end


@implementation Deck

- (NSMutableArray *)cards
{
    if (!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _cards;
}

- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
    if (atTop)
    {
        [self.cards insertObject:card atIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.cards addObject:card];
    }
}

- (Card *)drawRandonCard
{
    Card *randomCard = nil;

    if (self.cards.count)
    {
        unsigned index = arc4random() % self.cards.count;
        randomCard = self.cards[index];
        [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }

    return randomCard;
}

@end
```

PlayingCardDeck.m

```
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCardDeck

- (id)init
{
    self = [self init];

    if (self)
    {
        for (NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits])
        {
            for (NSUInteger rank=1; rank <= [PlayingCard maxRank]; rank++)
            {
                PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
                card.suit = suit;
                card.rank = rank;
                [self addCard:card atTop:YES];
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PlayerCardDeck.m `self = [self init]` should be `self = [super init]`. That's causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Doooh! Hours looking at it blinded me to the obvious! Thanks Florian.